# UNION optional match node identifiers without collect/unwind (because unwind keeps unbinding preceding identifiers)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am collecting nodes through optional matches, then want to match the aggregate of those nodes. If I use collect then unwind with null collections, I lose all identifiers preceding the unwind. Is there a way to do this? (essentially a union of optional matches)

```
MATCH (main {Identifier: "Main"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (main)-[:MULTI_JUMP_PATH1]->(nodes1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (main)-[:MULTI_JUMP_PATH2]->(nodes2)
WITH main, collect(nodes1) + collect(nodes2) as nodesunion
UNWIND
   CASE
      WHEN nodesunion = null
         THEN [null]
      ELSE nodesunion
   END AS nodes
WITH main, nodes
yada yada
```

When nodesunion is null, my main becomes unbound/null. I found some posts from 2015 that say this is a feature but that the case should take care of it, but it does not. Is it that my case is incorrect? If not, is there a workaround?  tia!

Comment: Can you open a new question (with more complete info) for your addendum, and restore this question to its original form? It would be very hard to follow the original question and answers (and the new question and answers) otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return the distinct nodes that are connected by either type of relationship to the desired "Main" node(s):

```
MATCH (main {Identifier: "Main"})
UNWIND
  [(main)-[:MULTI_JUMP_PATH1]->(n1) | n1] +
  [(main)-[:MULTI_JUMP_PATH2]->(n2) | n2] AS node
RETURN DISTINCT main, node
```